# View over GLSurfaceView not visible on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, glsurfaceview

I have GLSurfaceView, and small LinearLayout with buttons on top, representing menu. This layout is hidden by default, and appear from bottom of the screen (by TranslateAnimation) when user tap some button. (Also tried to show without animation - no success).

Everything works just fine on all devices and emulators I can get.
But I got feedback from users, that menu is not appearing at all, or sometime it can appear after 5-10 taps.

Probably, by some reasons, gl surface rendered above activity layer, but should be behind.

Known problematic devices is Huawei y300 with Android 4.1.1, LG Optimus L5, Galaxy Tab 7.7 SCH-I815, also got many reports from different devices and Android versions, but can't reproduce it.

setup:

```
view.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888);
view.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0); // alpha set to 8, else crash on Genymotion emulator
// tried to comment 2 lines above - no success
view.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

I tried setZOrderMediaOverlay(true), and setZOrderOnTop(false) - didn't help.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Layers do not change z-order willy-nilly.  My guess would be that this is not about the GLSurfaceView layer, but about the other UI elements failing to be drawn.  If the layer were mis-configured, the menu would *never* appear, rather than sometimes appearing after several attempts.  You should probably focus your attention on the animated layout.

Comment: I have mode without OpenGL - game rendered to canvas on usual view, layout hierarchy exactly same, in this mode all work correct on problematic devices. Also views not added dynamically, just show/hide, so z-order not changed. So I think the problem in composing GLSurface with usual views, what depends on hardware, I believe.

Comment: You are facing this this issue may be , you developed game considering only one version of open GL. New devices have 2.0 & latest 3.0 . so ,may be this one is the concern your GL is not working properly.

Comment: No, I using GL 1.0. And if requested version not supported it will not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution (I got problematic device and test it).

There is some tricky optimization with dirty rects, like a mask area where layers blending must be done, but these rects are not updated when needed. Calling parentView.requestLayout() after show hidden views forces to validate these dirty rects.

Explanation for appearing menu after 5-10 taps was occasional ads banner update (or some other event), which probably calls requestLayout.